# Get the file list in the WebServer from the appserver

Tags: java, jsp, web-applications, webserver, application-server

Hi all 
Is there any methods to fetch the File List in the Web server from the Application Server using JAVA?

i am finding something like

```
new file ("/webserver_context_root/folder/")
```

method that using the relative path to get the web server's resources from the app server...

PS : The reverse proxy has been set between the web and application servers.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The HTTP protocol provides no standard way to list a "folder".  Indeed, the HTTP and URI / URL specs don't even recognize "folder" as a concept.

If the folder notion is meaningful for your website then there are two approaches that could work:

- Many webservers can be configured to produce a listing (e.g. in HTML) for a URL that corresponds to a folder in the webservers content space.  (This is usually turned off for security reasons.)  You can "scrape" this HTML to extract the list of names of things in the folder.
- You could implement a RESTful service to return a list of the "files" in a "folder" as (say) JSON or XML.

Note however, that both approaches will be specific to that website.  They won't work for arbitrary websites.  I'm also assuming that the "application server" accesses the "web server" using HTTP. If it can access it some other way, there may be other solutions.

Comment: thanks for the info... however, for some reason, i cannot use the HTTP/HTTPS method to get the web server resource...the application server has blocked all HTTP connection to the webserver...i just can use the relative path (thanks the reverse proxy) to access the web server using javascript...sigh...

Comment: @Cube - you are doing a really bad job of explaining what is going on.  I haven't a clue what you are talking about.